# how can i set a default value using jstl in a drop down

Tags: jstl

am getting a list of values in the below itereate logic.I need to set one particular value "Count"  as a default value in my dropdown

```
<logic:new name="val">
<logic:iterate name="val" id="Opt" type="parameter">
<c:set var="Key" value="${fn:trim(Opt.key)}"/>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${Key == selectedValue}">
<option value="${Key}" selected="selected" ><c:out value="${Opt.Value}" /></option>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<option value="${Key}"><c:out value="${opt.Value}" /></option>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose> </logic:iterate>
```

I tried as below but its not defaulting the value in drop down.Any body can suggest any other way to set the default.

```
<c:if test="${paramName == 'Count'}">
<option value="-"><c:out value="${defaultLabel}"/> </option>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i understood your question correctly or not but you can set the default value before starting your iteration

```
<option value="-" selected="selected" >your Default Value</option>
```

if my understanding is wrong please help me understand your requirement.

Comment: Hi I tried as you said but its not defaulting me the value.For eg. I am having my values in the drop down as Counts,Counts+1,Counts+2 and Counts+3.I want to default the value Counts in the dropdown

Comment: Even i tried as you said                                                           <c:if test="${paramName == 'Count'}">
<option value="-" selected="selected"><c:out value="${defaultLabel}"/> </option>
</c:if>               but still i am getting the select a value as my default value.